# Image not showing IE(all the versions)

Tags: image, internet-explorer

i tried all the versions of ie but it is not showing only 1 image.

```
<asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/FlorDecor.jpg" BorderColor="AliceBlue" BorderStyle="None" Height="126px" Width="90px" />
```

i tried placing this image outside the folder and giving

- url = "FlorDecor.jpg"
- url = "../FlorDecor.jpg"
- url="~/FlorDecor.jpg"

i tried all this stuff pls help me..

Comment: Can you give more detail? Do you have a url?

Comment: Is there, in fact, an image `FlorDecor.jpg` in the `images` directory? How is your site structured? From what page are you trying to accesses it? Where is the page located?

Comment: nope i am developing it. Hvnt uploaded it
 <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td valign="bottom">
              
          <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/FlorDecor.jpg" BorderColor="AliceBlue" BorderStyle="None" Height="126px" Width="90px" /> 
                </td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

this is my code

Comment: does it display in other browsers?

Comment: yes there is an image in images directory i checked dat out.
i am using table tr td structure 

it is in master page and i am trying to access it from homepage or default page

Comment: yup it is displaying in firefox as well as chrome

Comment: there is images folder in which this image is. i tried many things, i googled it but didnt get any help. There are many solutions but they are not working 4 me so i tried pasting that image on the website folder and accessing it.  please guys help me....

Answer (score 0):

Your URL references were not all valid in Silverlight (should have been "images/FlorDecor.jpg" **if the file is in the images folder of your Silverlight App**).

Silverlight uses different URL methods depending on whether the image is in the Silverlight project or somewhere on the source website (or an external site).

If the problem persists the cause is more likely that your JPG is not compatible for some reason.

Convert it to a PNG with [Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net/) or similar to test that theory, or just grab another JPG from the Internet instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use .jpg file, use .png. It will works.

Comment: JPG are best for photos in Silverlight (or elsewhere). The compression is much higher. 

PNG is best suited to non-lossy images or requiring transparency.